# Retroactively change commits in git

Tags: git

I am working on my own feature branch and forgot to change the firmware version string at the start of the branch. How can I go back and change the firmware version in my source file so that starting from the first commit it will be the new firmware version number?

Here is a map of my repository:

```
* 692F98C (HEAD, feature/my_new_feature) Woops forgot to increment version number
* 329AC5A Added some functionality for something or other
* 27BDF1F Began my feature branch!
* 041BAC2 (origin/develop, develop)
....
```

The firmware version at commit `041BAC2` is `"0.4.0"`. At commit `27BDF1F` the version number should have been incremented to `0.5.0` but I forgot to do it until `692F98C`. How can I get out of this mess?

Note that I have not pushed this branch to origin or anyone else yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rebase -i`.

1. Make a new commit which bumps the version to 0.5.0
2. Run `git rebase -i $COMMIT` where `$COMMIT` is the last commit which is supposed to be 0.4.0.
3. Move your new commit to the top of the text file that `rebase -i` gives you.

Comment: Oh that's what rebase does! Thank you so much! I'm still learning git obviously.

Comment: Just don't use `-f` or `--force` unless you know what data you're messing with.